# How can I try reading data from a file or else return empty string?

Tags: file, rust, match

I would like to read a specific line of a file, if the:

- file does not exist
- file cannot be open
- the number of lines is less that the one that I want

just return an empty string.

Consider the following examples:

```rust
let wifi = "".to_string();
if let Ok(wifi_file) = fs::read_to_string("/proc/net/wireless") {
    if let Some(wifi_level) = wifi_file.lines().nth(2) {
        let wifi = format!("{:.0} dBa ", wifi_level
            .split_whitespace()
            .collect::<Vec<&str>>()[3]
            .parse::<f32>()
            .unwrap()
        );
    }
}
// wifi is out of scope
```

```rust
let wifi = match fs::read_to_string("/proc/net/wireless") {
    Ok(s) => format!("{:.0} dBA", s.lines()
        .nth(2)
        .expect("Unable to open")
        .split_whitespace()
        .collect::<Vec<&str>>()[3]
        .parse::<f32>()
        .unwrap()),
    Err(_) => "".to_string(),
};
// thread 'main' panicked at 'Unable to open', ...
```

Am I missing something obvious about `match`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have an answer, but this code can be simplified if you encapsulate it in a function returning an `Option` and use `?` for none-propagation:

```
fn get_wifi(path: &str, n: usize) -> Option<String> {
    let file = std::fs::read_to_string(path).ok()?;
    let level = file.lines().nth(n)?;
    let value = level.split_whitespace().nth(3)?.parse::<f32>().ok()?;
    
    Some(format!("{:.0} dBa ", value))
}
```

You can then call it like this:

```
let wifi = get_wifi("/proc/net/wireless", 2).unwrap_or_default();
```

Answer (score 2):

In your first code, you are declaring `wifi` variable again instead of using the already declared variable.

Working code:

```
let mut wifi = "".to_string();
if let Ok(wifi_file) = fs::read_to_string("/proc/net/wireless") {
    if let Some(wifi_level) = wifi_file.lines().nth(2) {
        wifi = format!("{:.0} dBa ", wifi_level
            .split_whitespace()
            .collect::<Vec<&str>>()[3]
            .parse::<f32>()
            .unwrap()
        );
    }
}
```

Second code is working without any changes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The second code crashes when the file contains only 2 lines instead of 3.

Comment: @yellowhat actually it crashes if the third line doesn't contain a valid `f32`. To handle this case don't call `unwrap`, but use another `if let Ok (float_level) = …` instead.

Comment: For my understanding: does the `match`(`Ok` / `Err`) just covers `fs::read_to_string("/proc/net/wireless")` not `s.lines().nth(2).expect("Unable to open") ...`?

Comment: @yellowhat Rust doesn't have exceptions like C++/Java/Python that can break the control flow. In Rust, `match` is just the same as `switch … case` in those languages. OTOH, `expect` (like `unwrap`) means: "crash if the expectation is not met" (e.g. if the value is `Err` for a `Result` or `None` for an `Option`).